# Permission Error just started on AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to figure what's going on with my deployment of an AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy.   I'm getting  this error and I cannot deploy my node.js app to EB. This site is not live so I dropped the environment and started over and no luck.   And i did try the hack I saw on here from 2016 when this issue seemed prevalant (see beanstalk .ebextension below). The sample app deploys fine if I choose it.  I was able to deploy this same app last night, but all day today I'm getting the following permissions error:

```
> node@11.3.0 preinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node
  > node installArchSpecificPackage

  Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/.npm/_cacache/tmp/b681df8c'
  npm ERR! cb() never called!


files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm/
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out if anyone is interested.   It was a pain.   I don't know what I did, but somehow I added a node dependency in my package.json to 11.3.0.   EB does not support this version.  I uninstalled node.js from my app, deleted the node_modules directory, ran a npm install on my project and tried again.  This time it worked.   Wow.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node": "^11.3.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.43",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```